# Intelij: Re-compiling when application is running?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

When using `Intelij IDEA`, is it possible to re-compile code as my application is running?

I.e. if I make a change to a `Java` class and I do not want to re-start my app to start using the change, is there a functionality that allows this?

I ask as currently to see my changes I am having to re-start my application each time which is taking a long time.

Comment: depends. GWT DEv mode allows you to do this on the front-end of your GWT app, or JRebel can help you out for other web-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the debugging tool to change code on the go, just save the new code you have put in (inside IntelliJ), while keeping the application going. To get into debug mode click run and Debug 'nameOfApplication'. Hope this helped.